# How to generate AUTOMATIC Control Number in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

How can I generate AUTOMATIC unique control number in one of my table in my database `mysql`.

When I Add entry in the table, I want the `control_no` column in the table `issuance_tbl` be automatically updated with control number in this format `1111-00001`.
so when I add another entry in the table, it should insert `1111-00002`. just add incrementally.

thanks. :)

Comment: do it in application level.

Comment: You want to generate it with PHP or with MySQL query? And... what have you tried, ofcourse?

Comment: actually I have a form, I am using PHP.. is it possible to do this in PHP? my idea is to use the auto increment in  table. but i don't know how to change the format.

Comment: Use the autoincrement and append its value to a string `'1111-'`.

Answer (score 1):

If you for some reason **really** need it to be implemented in MySQL rather than on an application level then you can achieve your goal with a help of a separate table for sequencing and a trigger.

Table schema:

```sql
CREATE TABLE issuance_seq_tbl
(
  id int not null auto_increment primary key
);
CREATE TABLE issuance_tbl
(
  control_no varchar(10) not null default ''
);
```

The trigger:

```sql
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER tg_bi_issuance_tbl
BEFORE INSERT ON issuance_tbl
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO issuance_seq_tbl() VALUES();
  SET NEW.control_no = CONCAT('1111-', LPAD(LAST_INSERT_ID(), 5, '0'));
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c4c0f/1)** demo

Comment: @ChocoMartin Did it help after all?